# マルチプロセスで処理する際、例外をキャッチした上で処理を継続したいです

Tags: python

## やりたいこと

以下のコードのように、Pythonの`multiprocessing.Pool`を使って並列に処理したいです。

```
import multiprocessing

def foo(i):
    if i%2==0:
        raise RuntimeError("偶数")
    return i

with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as p:
    result = p.map(foo, [1, 3, 5])
    print(result)
    # => [1, 3, 5]
```

## 質問

以下のように`[1,2,3]`をmap関数に渡すと、`i=2`のときにRuntimeErrorがスローされます。

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as p:
    result = p.map(foo, [1,2,3])
```

```
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-102-bbf59efb0d82>", line 3, in foo
    raise RuntimeError("偶数")
RuntimeError: 偶数
"""
```

`i=2`のときの例外をキャッチした上で、`i=1`, `i=3`のときの結果も取得したいです。どのようなコードを書けばよいでしょうか？

以下のコードのように、`foo`関数の中でtry/exceptすれば、`i=1`, `i=3`のときの結果を取得できます。
しかし、本来try/exceptはfoo関数の呼び出し元で行うべきなので、できればこの方法は採用したくありません。

```
def foo(i):
    try:
        if i%2==0:
            raise RuntimeError("custom")
        return i
    except Exception
        return None
```

Answer (score 2):

[ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819075/9105334)にあるように、[`imap`メソッド](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap)を使ってイテレーターを取得し、例外を処理しながらイテレーターを進めていくのはいかがでしょうか。

```py
import multiprocessing

def foo(i):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"偶数: {i}")
    return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as p:
        result_iterator = p.imap(foo, [1, 2, 3])
        while True:
            try:
                result = next(result_iterator)
                print(result)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```